# When does $|X^n|\leq |k^X|$ without the axiom of Choice?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

We're working in $\sf{ZF}$ set theory, we assume $n$ is a finite cardinal, and the set $X$ is not finite. My question is: what's the smallest cardinal $k$ for which $\sf{ZF}$ proves $|X^n| \leq |k^X|$? We know that such $k$ must exist and be finite, since $|X^n|\leq |2^X|^n=|(2^n)^X|$ proves $k\leq 2^n$. The case $n=0$ is trivial, $k_0=1$. The case $n=1$ isn't much harder, $k_1=2$. The analogous question for $\sf{ZFC}$ is also trivial, $k_n=2$ for all $n>0$, but without Choice the problem seems rather difficult even for $n=2$.

I was able to prove the upper bound $k_n\leq n+1$ for all $n$, and I suspect this is optimal. In particular, I suspect that for each $n$, it's consistent that there exists infinite $X$ for which $|X^n|\not\leq |n^X|$. More strongly, I suspect it's consistent that there exists $X$ for which all $n$ have $|X^n|\not\leq |n^X|$. Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with forcing techniques, so I don't know how to prove this. It might be possible to establish a nice lower bound by considering the case where $X$ is an amorphous set, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I would accept any answer that at least finds $k_3$.

---

To prove that $k_n\leq n+1$, I'll start by proving $|X^n|\leq n^n|(n+1)^X|$. Consider a function $f:n\to X$. We use $f$ to define the functions $p:X\to (n+1)$ and $g:n\to n$ like so.
$$p(x):=\begin{cases}n &: x\notin f[n] \\ \min\{j<n : x=f(j)\} &: x\in f[n]\end{cases}$$
$$g(j):=p(f(j))$$

Notice that the map $f\mapsto (g,p)$ sends $X^n\to n^n\times (n+1)^X$. This map is moreover an injection, since we have $p^{-1}[g(j)]=\{f(j)\}$ for all $j<n$. The intuition behind this strategy is that the function $p$ injects the image of $f$ into $n$, and then we use this numbering to compress $f$ into a function $g:n\to n$. Since $p$ can be used to decompress $g$ back into $f$, we have an injection. From these arguments, it follows that $|X^n|\leq n^n|(n+1)^X| \leq |(n+2)^X|$ and therefore $k_n\leq n+2$.

For $n>0$, the above strategy can be further improved to give $k_n\leq n+1$. To do this, let $M=(n+1)\times(n+2)$, and find an injection $\iota:M\to X$, which is possible since $X$ is infinite. For each $j<n+1$, define the sets $B_j=\{\iota(j,i) : i<n\}$ and $I_j=\{\iota(j,i) : n\leq i<n+2\}$, so that the collection of all $I_j$ and $B_j$ are pairwise disjoint, and each $|B_j|=n$ and $|I_j|=2$. Using the same map $f\mapsto (g,p)$ as before, we notice that there necessarily exists $j<n+1$ for which we have the image $p[B_j\cup I_j]=\{n\}$. Relying on that fact, we define the map $(g,p)\mapsto q\in (n+1)^X$ as follows.
$$J:=\min\{j<n+1 : p[B_j\cup I_j]=\{n\}\}$$
$$q(x):=\begin{cases} p(x) &: x\notin (I_J\cup B_J) \\ 0 &: x\in I_J \\ g(i) &: x\in B_J\land x=\iota(J,i) \end{cases}$$

To recover $(g,p)$ from $q$, first we recover $J<n+1$ as the unique number satisfying $q[I_J]=\{0\}$. Now we easily recover $g$ via $g(i)=q(\iota(J,i))$, and for $p$ we have $p(x)=q(x)$ when $x\notin (I_J\cup B_J)$ and $p(x)=n$ otherwise. The recoverability of $(g,p)$ from $q$ proves this is an injection. The intuition behind this strategy is that $p$ leaves a lot of empty space on which $p(x)=n$ is constant, and we can fit enough information in that space to encode $g$. We partition a subset of $X$ into some blocks $B_j$ and indicators $I_j$, and based on the structure of $p$, we're guaranteed that some block/indicator pair will be vacant. We choose one of these vacant block/indicator pairs, encode $g$ inside the block $B_j$, and enable the indicator $I_j$ so we know where to look to decode $g$. By composing our injections, we can send $f\mapsto q$ to prove $|X^n|\leq |(n+1)^X|$ and thus $k_n\leq n+1$ for all $n>1$. A similar strategy should prove $m|X^n|\leq |(n+1)^X|$ for all finite $m$, which is an interesting albeit unrelated result.

Comment: Very neat question! In the basic Fraenkel model for set theory with atoms, there is an infinite set $X$ such that $|X^2|\not\le 2^{|X|}$. This was shown by Specker in 1957 (and from this it follows that this is consistent with ZF without atoms). Specker also showed (in 1954) that if $|X|\ge5$, then $2^{|X|}\not\le|X^2|$, so $k_2=3$, though I imagine you have encountered this before.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I have indeed seen the $|X^2|\not\leq 2^{|X|}$ result about $\sf{ZFA}$, which is why I set the bar for an answer to be $k_3$, but nonetheless I don't understand the techniques used to transfer the $k_2$ results from $\sf{ZFA}$ into $\sf{ZF}$. What text would you recommend about that subject in particular?

P.S. if you're interested in the answer to my question, I suspect I have a strategy to prove $k_n=n+1$ which will be finished in a few days.

Comment: Jech's "The axiom of choice" is good, even if a bit brief. Chapter 6 is about the transfer theorems. There is also Halbeisen's "Combinatorial set theory"; take a look at Chapter 17. And yes, I am definitely interested.

Comment: Do you know whether you can get $|X|\cdot n^{|X|}\le (n+1)^{|X|}$?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Very interesting question! I think the answer is yes. Naively we can inject $X\times n^X\to n\times (n+1)^X$ by sending $(x_0,p)\mapsto (p(x_0), q)$, where $q(x_0)=n$ and $q(x)=p(x)$ otherwise. This $q$ has a lot of "empty space" where $q(x)\neq n$, so a modified block/indicator strategy can encode extra information inside this $q$, namely the information about $p(x_0)$. A similar strategy generally proves $|X|^m\cdot n^{|X|}\leq (n+m)^{|X|}$ for infinite $X$, and this $n+m$ is optimal since we proved $|X|^{n-1}\leq n^{|X|}$ and we cannot prove $|X|^{n+m-1}\leq (n+m-1)^{|X|}$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Minor correction, the base $n+m$ is optimal so long as $n>0$, but not necessarily when $n=0$, albeit the case $n=0$ is trivial anyway. Also I should clarify, the modified block/indicator strategy I mention is more complicated than the one I used in my original question. We can always choose a block which avoids $\{x_0\}$, but without AC we can't always choose a block that avoids $D(q)$, so we have to account for the possibility that we overwrite nontrivial portions of $q$. If you ping me in chat, I can elaborate on how I work around that, or post a question and I'll answer

Comment: Thanks! Maybe posting the question/answer may be better so it is available not just to us.

Comment: (Posted the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We prove $k_n=n+1$ by considering the case where $X$ is a [strictly amorphous set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set), which is known to be consistent with $\sf{ZF}$. Since $X$ is amorphous, any partition of $X$ will contain at most one infinite part. Moreover since $X$ is strictly amorphous, any partition of $X$ into finite sets will be composed almost entirely of singletons. We'll rely on the four results established in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4631039/813439), listed below, plus another lemma and theorem we prove below.

**Lemma 1:** *Given wellorderable $\alpha$ and $f:X \to \alpha$, the image $f[X]$ is finite.*
**Theorem 1:** *For $n\in\omega$ and $F:X^n\to [X]^{<\omega}$, the set $\bigcup\{F(p)\setminus p[n] : p\in X^n\}$ is finite.*
**Theorem 2:** *For $F:[X]^{<\omega}\to [X]^{<\omega}$, the set $\bigcup\{F(S)\setminus S : S\in [X]^{<\omega}\}$ is finite.*

**Lemma 2:** *Given wellorderable $\alpha$ and $f:X \to \alpha$, there's unique $s \in \alpha$ having $f^{-1}(s)$ be infinite.*
**proof:** The image of $f$ is finite, so the preimages of $f$ form a finite partition of $X$. Since $X$ is amorphous, exactly one of these partitions will be infinite.$\Box$
**Definition:** Given well orderable $\alpha$ and $f:X \to \alpha$, define $L(f):=s$ as in the above lemma.
**Definition:** Given well orderable $\alpha$ and $f:X \to \alpha$, define $D(f):=\{x : f(x)\neq L(f)\}$, which is finite.

**Theorem 3:** *Given $k\in\omega$ and $F:k^X \to [X]^{<\omega}$, the set $\bigcup\{F(p)\setminus D(p) : p\in k^X\}$ is finite.*
**proof:** For each $S\in[X]^{<\omega}$, define $G(S):=\bigcup\{F(p) : D(p)=S, p\in k^X\}$. The set of $p$ quantified over by $G(S)$ has a natural injection into $k\times k^S$, which is finite, thus $G(S)$ is a finite union of finite sets. Since $G:[X]^{<\omega}\to [X]^{<\omega}$, it follows that the set $\bigcup\{G(S)\setminus S : S\in[X]^{<\omega}\}$ is finite, and this is a superset of $\bigcup\{F(p)\setminus D(p) : p\in k^X\}$, proving our claim.$\Box$

---

For our strategy, we take any $n>1$ and assume $|X^n|\leq |k^X|$. This implies there's an injection $Q:X^n\to k^X$, and we exploit the properties of strict amorphousness to prove $n+1\leq k$. To do this, we'll prove that there exists an injective $f\in X^n$ such that the map $x\mapsto Q(f)(x)$ is injective over $x\in f[n]$, and moreover that $Q(f)(x)\neq L(Q(f))$ on the same domain. Once we find such $f$, the injective condition implies that $|Q(f)[f[n]]|=|f[n]|=n$, and since there exists $x\in X$ for which $Q(f)(x)=L(Q(f))$, where necessarily $x\notin f[n]$, it follows that $|Q(f)[X]|\geq n+1$. Since $Q(f)[X]\subseteq k$, it will follow that $n+1\leq k$.

To begin, consider the map $f\mapsto D(Q(f))$, which sends $X^n\to [X]^{<\omega}$. By theorem 1, it follows that the set $B:=\bigcup\{D(Q(f))\setminus f[n] : f\in X^n\}$ is a finite subset of $X$. This lets us decompose $Q$ in a unique way, simply by describing its behavior on $f[n]$, on $B$, and in the remaining cases where it equals $L(Q(f))$. For simplicity,
for each $j<k$ let $\sigma_j:k\to k$ be the permutation which is identity except for swapping $j$ with $0$. Using this language, we form an injection $Q[X^n]\to (k\times k^B)\times k^X$, defined so that $Q(f)\mapsto (g_f, p_f)$, where $g_f,p_f$ are defined as follows.
$$\begin{align}
g_f&:=(L(Q(f)),Q_f\restriction_B) \\
p_f(x)&:=\begin{cases} \sigma_{L(Q(f))}(Q(f)(x)) &: x\in f[n] \\ 0 &: x\notin f[n]\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

It's not too hard to prove that if $(g_f,p_f) = (g_h, p_h)$ then necessarily $Q(f)=Q(h)$ and consequently $f=h$, so the map $f\mapsto (g_f,p_f)$ is injective. For simplicity we'll label $N=k\times k^B$, which is a finite set,  hence $g_f$ takes on only finitely many values. Now we prove our first goal, which is that for most $f$, we have $p_f$ nonzero on the image of $f$. To prove this, we consider the functions $F:N\times k^X \to [X]^{<\omega}$ and then $F_0:k^X\to [X]^{<\omega}$ defined as follows.
$$\begin{align}
F(g,p)&:=\begin{cases} P^{-1}(g,p)[n] &: (g,p)\in P[X^n] \\ \emptyset &: (g,p)\notin P[X^n] \end{cases} \\
F'(p)&:=\bigcup_{g\in N} F(g,p)
\end{align}$$
$$X_0:=\{x\in X : \exists(f\in X^n), x\in f[n]\land p_f(x)=0\}$$

The function $F$ works since $P$ is injective, so whenever $(g,p)$ is in the image $P[X^n]$, then $P^{-1}(g,p)\in X^n$ and then $F(g,p)$ is the finite image of that $n$-tuple. The function $F'$ just unions $F(g,p)$ over the finitely many $g\in N$, so $F'(p)$ is also finite. Every $x\in X_0$ admits $f\in X^n$ with both $x\in f[n]$ and $p_f(x)=0$, thus $x\in (F(g_f,p_f)\setminus D(p_f))\subseteq (F'(p_f)\setminus D(p_f))$. It follows that $X_0\subseteq\bigcup\{F'(p)\setminus D(p) : p\in k^X\}$, but because $F':k^X\to [X]^{<\omega}$, the set is finite by theorem 3, thus $X_0$ is finite. It follows that, where $X\setminus X_0$ is a cofinite subset of $X$, all $f\in (X\setminus X_0)^n$ and all $x\in f[n]$ have $p_f(x)\neq 0$. Now we work toward our second goal, that for most $f$, we have $p_f$ injective on the image of $f$. To begin, we'll restrict the domain $X$ so that, for each $t<n$, the evaluations $p_f(f(t))$ are constant across all injective $f$. To do this, we recursively define the functions $F_{(t,j)}:X^{n-j}\to k$ across all $j\leq n$, and the functions $E_{(t,j)}:X^{n-j}\to[X]^{<\omega}$ for $0<j<n$, and finally the set $X_1$, as follows.
$$\begin{align}
F_{(t,0)}(f)&:=p_f(f(t)) \\
F_{(t,j+1)}(x_0,\cdots,x_{n-j-2})&:=L(x_{n-j-1}\mapsto F_{(t,j)}(x_0,\cdots,x_{n-j-1})) \\
\ell_t&:=F_{(t,n)}(\emptyset) \\
E_{(t,j+1)}(x_0,\cdots,x_{n-j-2})&:=D(x_{n-j-1}\mapsto F_{(t,j)}(x_0,\cdots,x_{n-j-1})) \\
X_1&:=\bigcup_{t<k}\bigcup_{j=1}^{j<n}\bigcup\{E_{(t,j)}(f)\setminus f[n-j] : f\in X^{n-j}\}
\end{align}$$

By theorem 1, it follows quickly that the set $X_1$ is a union of finitely many finite sets, so it's finite. By continuing the recursion up to $j=n$, we get $F_{(t,n)}:X^0\to k$, and the only function $f\in X^0$ is the empty function, hence we get $\ell_t\in k$ as a constant independent of $f$. Taking any injective $f:n\to (X\setminus X_1)$, each integer $j\in(0,n)$ has $f(n-j-1)\notin E_{(t,j+1)}(f\restriction_{n-j})$ and consequently $F(f\restriction_{n-j})=F(f\restriction_{n-j-1})$, and by finite induction it follows that $p_t(f(t))=F_{(t,0)}(f)=F_{(t,n)}(\emptyset)=\ell_t$. Since $\ell_t$ is independent of $f$, we see that indeed $p_t(f(t))$ is constant across all injective $f\in (X\setminus X_1)^n$.

To complete our proof, we show that the map $n\to k$ defined by $t\mapsto \ell_t$ is injective and nonzero. To do this, let $Y=X\setminus(X_0\cup X_1)$, which is an infinite subset of $X$. Taking any $f\in Y^n$, we'll have $p_t(f(t))\neq 0$ by construction of $X_0$, but we'll also have $p_t(f(t))=\ell_t$ by construction of $X_1$, thus $\ell_t\neq 0$ as desired. To prove injectivity, take any $i<j<n$ and by contradiction suppose $\ell_i=\ell_j$. Select any injective $f'\in X^{n\setminus\{i,j\}}$, and for each $g\in N$ we define the relation $C_g$ as follows.
$$C_g:=\{(\{f(i),f(j)\},f(i)) : f\in Y^n\text{ is injective, }g_f=g, f'\subseteq f\}$$

This relation $C_g$ actually defines a choice function for some collection of unordered pairs in $Y$. To see that $C_g$ is a function, suppose we have two satisfying $f_1,f_2$ each of which had $(\{f_u(i),f_u(j)\} f_u(i))\in C_g$, but such that $f_1(i)\neq f_2(i)$. Because $g_{f_1}=g=g_{f_2}$, the injectivity of our map $f\mapsto (g_f,p_f)$ implies that $p_{f_1}\neq p_{f_2}$. It's easily shown that $f_1(i)=f_2(j)$ and $f_1(j)=f_2(i)$, and consequently $f_1[n]=f_2[n]$, thus $p_{f_1}(x)=p_{f_2}(x)=0$ whenever $x\in X\setminus f_u[n]$. For $x=f_1(i)=f_2(j)$ we get $p_{f_1}(x)=\ell_i=\ell_j=p_{f_2}(x)$, and this similarly happens when $x=f_1(j)$. The only remaining $x$ are in the image of $f'$, but there must be $t\neq i,j$ for which $x=f'(t)=f_1(t)=f_2(t)$, and thus $p_{f_1}(x)=\ell_t=p_{f_2}(t)$. This proves $p_{f_1}(x)=p_{f_2}(x)$ for all $x\in X$, thus $p_{f_1}=p_{f_2}$, contradicting our assumption that $f_1\neq f_2$. With this contradiction, it's established that $C_g$ is a function defined on some domain.

It's clear by definition that whenever $(x,y)\in C_g$ then $y\in x$, thus $C_g$ is a choice function. We can merge these functions across all the $g\in N$ to get a choice function defined for every unordered pair in $Y$. Indeed, notice that if $x,y\in Y$ has both $x,y\notin f'[n\setminus\{i,j\}]$ and $x\neq y$, then the extended function $f=f'\cup\{(i,x),(j,y)\}$ obeys our conditions, and thus $C_{g_f}(\{x,y\})=x$. It follows that for nearly every pair $\{x,y\}$, there exists $g\in N$ for which $\{x,y\}\in\operatorname{dom}(C_g)$. Recalling that $g\in N$ and $N$ is a finite set, we can define some well order on $N$ and merge all the $C_g$ according to that ordering. The cases where no such $g$ exists can be handled manually, so we define the following choice function for all unordered pairs in $Y$.
$$C(\{x,y\}):=\begin{cases}
C_g(\{x,y\}) &: g=\min\{g'\in N : \{x,y\}\in\operatorname{dom}(C_g)\} \\
f(t) &: t=\min\{t'<n : f'(t)\in\{x,y\}\} \\
 x &: x=y\land (\{x,y\}\cap f'[n\setminus\{i,j\}])=\emptyset
\end{cases}$$

This is impossible however, as it contradicts the fact that $Y\subseteq X$ is an infinite subset of a strictly amorphous set, and thus is also strictly amorphous. To see why $C$ is impossible, define $H(x):=\{y\in Y : C(\{x,y\})=x\}$ and notice that, for all $x\neq y$, either $x\in H(y)$ or $y\in H(x)$, but not both. Letting $Y_0=\{x\in Y : |H(x)|\in \omega\}$, the map $x\mapsto H(x)$ sends $Y_0\to [Y]^{<\omega}$ and thus the union $\bigcup\{H(x)\setminus\{x\} : x\in Y_0\}$ is a finite set. If $Y_0$ were infinite, we could find distinct $x,y\in Y_0$ for which $y\notin H(x)$ and $x\notin H(y)$, but as established this is impossible. Since $Y_0$ is finite, it follows that the complement $Y_\infty:=\{x\in Y : |H(x)|\notin\omega\}$ is infinite. Now the map $x\mapsto (Y\setminus H(x))$ sends $Y_\infty\to [Y_\infty]^{<\omega}$, and again by theorem 1 the union $\bigcup\{(Y\setminus H(x)) : x\in Y_\infty\}$ is finite, so the intersection $\bigcap\{H(x) : x\in Y_\infty\}$ is cofinite. We can thus find distinct $x,y$ within $Y_\infty$ for which both $x\in H(y)$ and $y\in H(x)$, but this is again impossible.

We finally conclude that the map $n\to k$ defined by $t\mapsto \ell_t$ is both injective and nonzero, therefore $k-1=|k\setminus\{0\}|\geq n$ which proves $n\leq k+1$. Combining this with the upper bound $k_n\leq n+1$ proven in the question statement, we conclude that $k_n=n+1$. In summary: given standard finite cardinals $n,k$, we have that $\sf{ZF}$ proves $|X^n|\leq |k^X|$ for all infinite $X$ if and only if $n<k$. Moreover, it is consistent with $\sf{ZF}$ that there exists infinite $X$ such that all $n\in\omega$ have $|X^n|\not\leq |n^X|$. In particular, this happens whenever $X$ is strictly amorphous.

Comment: This is excellent!